# How to detect ServiceStack query collisions?

Tags: .net, rest, mono, servicestack

When using ServiceStack, if the caller uses a query parameter, such as "?Foo=3", and also provides a request body with a "Foo" property, a silent overwrite occurs.  The version in the body is discarded.

As a service author, I want to at least detect that this has happened, so that I can warn the user or disallow the call altogether.  I'd like to avoid writing custom extensions for this edge case scenario, is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect if the same property is in the QueryString and FormData in your Services or RequestFilters by inspecting the `IRequest`, e.g:

```
var hasSameProperty = Request.QueryString["Foo"] != null
    && Request.FormData["Foo"] != null;
```

Comment: I appreciate answers directly from the source, but I'm afraid that is super fiddly.  I don't suppose there's anything like Nancy has, were you can omit the queries from the "binding" phase?
That is, I'd simply like to ignore any extraneous query params that the caller may wedge into the query string.  I guess I can nuke the QueryString directly in a filter...

Comment: @SamKanai Right you can modify the HTTP Request in a filter or provide your [own custom Request binding](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#create-a-custom-request-dto-binder).